# refreshTokenWithAssertion results in error 400 Invalid JWT Signature

Tags: php, laravel, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I have been running this code to retrieve the access token in order to send FCM notifications for the past year however, it recently has been encountering an issue with executing `RefreshTokenWithAssertion()` where it repeatedly returns the error 400 ( `{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid JWT Signature."}` ) whilst running that function.

Attempted solution

1. I have tried to create a new google-service json file and replace it with the existing file in the project but the error faced is still the same
2. I have tried to hardcode the access token with one that has been derived from googleoauth playground which will allow the notification to be successfully sent out which indicates that everything else is working fine. The issue is only with **`refreshTokenWithAssertion()`**

What is the issue resulting in executing `**RefreshTokenWithAssertion()**`? How can I fix this issue

```
    $client = new \Google_Client();
    try {
        error_log("MADE IT HERE 1");
        $client->setAuthConfig($credentialsFilePath);
        error_log("MADE IT HERE 2");
        $client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging');
        error_log("MADE IT HERE 3");
        try {
            $client->refreshTokenWithAssertion();

         } catch (\Exception $e) {
             error_log('Exception during refreshTokenWithAssertion: ' . $e->getMessage());
            return null;  // Handle the error as needed in your application
         }
        error_log("MADE IT HERE 4");
        $token = $client->getAccessToken();
        error_log("MADE IT HERE 5");
    
        error_log('Token printed below:');
        error_log(json_encode($token));
    
        //$token['access_token'] = 'ya29.SAMPLE';
        return $token['access_token'];
    } catch (\Google\Exception $e) {
        error_log('Error during authentication: ' . $e->getMessage());
        return null;  // Handle the error as needed in your application
    }
```